# How to key in Asian names when making a flight reservation?

Tags: international-travel, languages

Let's assume my name is "A B C" for the argument's sake.

It's an Asian name, and it is written that way in the passport (more or less. Actually in the passport it is written with full phonetic marks and symbols - but is not unrecognisable from the non-phonetic one). The passport doesn't make it clear which part is the family, middle, and first name, it is understood that "A" is the family name, "B" is the middle name, and "B" is the first name.

I've booked an international flight, and the website requires to input names in order of first-middle-last. No problem here, I simply input them as they are. The problem is, when the ticket is issue, the name on the ticket will be "A/C B", unmatched with the one written in my passport. The name on the itinerary is "C B A", also not a match.

The reservation is already booked, and name change is impossible.

My gravest concern is with the given names. The whole given name as written in passport is "B C", while that on the ticket is "C B". Do you think it can be a problem?

Comment: Your question seems to be "My name on the ticket doesn't match my passport." The question I linked to says, in essence, "yes, it does match." Did you read the other question and its answer before you assumed it wasn't a duplicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While practice varies, it's perfectly normal for a name on a boarding pass to be "LAST/ FIRST MIDDLE MR", So "Mr John Jack Smith" appears as "SMITH/JOHN JACK MR". That seems to be exactly what has been done to your name.

I wouldn't worry about it. Airline staff are almost certainly familiar with a wide variety of international naming styles, and if they ask a brief explanation will probably sort it out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My concern is with the given names. The whole given name as written in passport is "Trung Kien", while that on the ticket is "Kien Trung". Do you think it can be a problem?

Comment: No. If you are asked, simply explain just as you did to us. "When I keyed in my name, my first name is Kien and my last name is Trung. On my passport they are listed in reverse order."